# How do I bin repetitive patterns?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In my Dataframe, I have a field which shows the status of a product ordered overtime. This can be 'New', 'Cancelled' , 'Filled' or 'Partial'. I have summarised the pattern of each Order(Orderid) recorded and made a count of the different patterns that can occur. However, this has resulted in over 1385 different patterns. I now want to compress these patterns down into bins where for example, if an order status is : New, New, Cancelled, New, Filled would be compressed to : New, Cancelled, New, Filled.

And this would be put in the same bin as a pattern of : New, New, New, Cancelled, Cancelled, New, New, Filled.

This is what the original data looks like:

[image: originalData]

Once grouped by each OrderID:

[image: Grouped By Orderid]

In order to see the patterns of OrderStatus that exist within the data, the following code was applied:

```
def status_transition_with_timestamp(each_grouped_df):
    sorted_df = each_grouped_df.sort_values('timestamp', ascending=True)
    concatenated_transition = ','.join(sorted_df['ostatus'])
    return concatenated_transition

result = df_grouped['ostatus'].agg(status_transition_with_timestamp)

result.groupby('ostatus').count()
```

Resulting in : [Output of counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWEcX.png)

Answer (score 0):

To remove consecutive duplicates use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
df['ostatus'] = df['ostatus'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([x for x, _ in groupby(x.split(','))]))
```

Then you'll have unique sequences and you can perform aggregation.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['New,New,Cancelled', 'New,Cancelled', 'Cancelled,New,Cancelled,New']})
df
#                        Status
#0            New,New,Cancelled
#1                New,Cancelled
#2  Cancelled,New,Cancelled,New

df['Status'] = df['Status'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([x for x, _ in groupby(x.split(','))]))
df
#                        Status
#0                New,Cancelled
#1                New,Cancelled
#2  Cancelled,New,Cancelled,New
```

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me the same results as before sorry.

Comment: @KanikaKaur You can now see how it works in example

Comment: I believe my original question might have been slightly misleading but I have updated it. Hope this makes sense. Thank you for your inputs